# Do any of the Spider-Women have a Spider-Sense?

Tags: marvel, spider-woman

Not speaking here of the most recent Spider-Women and girls, like Silk or Spider-Gwen; this would go without saying, as the same spider that bit Peter bit them, and thus transferred the same powers. I mean the more classic Spider-Women of Jessica Drew and Julia Carpenter. In the late 70s, in the *Spider Woman* cartoon, Jessica Drew *did* have a Spider-Sense that was even *more* effective than Peter's; she could actually *see* situations that were happening in her mind's eye, as a form of ESP, though she didn't have the same instantaneous "early warning" system which informed her movements like Peter.

However, this didn't line up at all with her comic book; her powers set, capacities and even origin were different. I know she has pheromone powers, but not sure about the Spider-Sense.

Julia Carpenter, the black-clad Spider-Woman of the West Coast Avengers, *should* have had a Spider-Sense, considering her webbing was psionic based. But I can't recall any instances of one being used in the comics.

Can anyone elaborate as to if this is true?

Comment: Both of Peter's AU daughters (Anna-May and Mayday) had it but they got it indirectly via their dad's mutated DNA from the Spider bite. I don't think any of the not chomped-by-a-spider women got it.

Venom had it for a while, which is REALLY weird.

Comment: Are you looking for something more than what their respective Wikipedia pages say? For both people, there is no initial indication of a spider-sense, but later they both developed greater powers that essentially performed the same role.

Comment: @JackBNimble Kind of, actually. Again, the information is conflicting, which is *why* I cited the 70s TV show for one earlier. Characters and abilities can grow and change, so its not an impossibility.

Comment: You'd be hard-pressed to find an ability that serves the same function referred to as Spidey sense on panel explicitly. Unequivocal on panel feats that lend credence to the characters having a homologue is something I'll look for. Will update an answer if I find one.

Comment: @GordonBennett, could you point me to the comic books wherein Venom had spidey sense?